# How to bind column headers and rows dynamically using xml in jqgrid/Jtable

Tags: jquery, xml, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Hi Have an xml which I need to display in the Jqgrid. Can any one please help in getting this working. If i am missing any other settings in the code please let me know

My xml data :

```
<entry>
<properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <property>
    <name>header1</name>
    <value>value 1.1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Header2</name>
    <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx</url>
    <value>value 1.2 </value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>header 3</name>
    <value>value 1.3 </value>
  </property>
</properties>
</entry>
<entry>
  <properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <property>
      <name>header1</name>
      <value>value 2.1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Header2</name>
      <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx</url>
      <value>value 2.2 </value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>header 3</name>
      <value>value 2.3</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
</entry>
```

Binding JqGrid like below but not working

```
function loadXMLDoc(data)
{
    $("#loadXMLData").jqGrid({
    url: 'local',
    datatype: "xml",
    height: 'auto',
    colModel: [
        { name:xmlmap: function (obj) {
                return $(obj).attr('name');
            }}
            , width: 80, sorttype: 'int',
            xmlmap: function (obj) {
                return $(obj).attr('value');
            }           
    ],
    xmlReader: {
        root: "properties",
        row: "property",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    loadonce: true,
    rowNum: 1000
});
```

I need the out put in below format

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      header 1
      </th>
    <th>
      header 2
      </th>
    <th>
      header 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 1.1</td>
    <td>value 1.2</td>
    <td>value 1.3</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 2.1</td>
    <td>value 2.2</td>
    <td>value 2.3</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 3.1</td>
    <td>value 3.2</td>
    <td>value 3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try xmlstring datatype, mentioned in below example

```
<script>
var mystr =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<invoices>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <cell>data1</cell>
            <cell>data2</cell>
            <cell>data3</cell>
            <cell>data4</cell>
            <cell>data5</cell>
            <cell>data6</cell>    
        </row>
    </rows>
</invoices>";

jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'xmlstring',
    datastr : mystr,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'invid', index:'invid', width:55, sorttype:'int'}, 
      {name:'invdate', index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:'date', datefmt:'Y-m-d'}, 
      {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:80, align:'right', sorttype:'float'}, 
      {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:80, align:'right', sorttype:'float'}, 
      {name:'total', index:'total', width:80, align:'right', sorttype:'float'}, 
      {name:'note', index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'My first grid'
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690289/how-to-assign-xml-data-to-jqgrid)

Comment: if you have seen my xml. It says my column and rows are dynamic. I need to decide based on the value given in xml. Like header 1, herader 2 etc. All this i need to pick it up from the xml itself

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is dynamic or not, you can put it in a local `var` as mentioned in my example and move forward.

Comment: Any hint to convert the xml to json?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer this SO post for [Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1773571/5104101) or follow this link to [Convert XML to JSON](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json)

If you have the provision of generating source XML file(s) then, instead of later converting it to JSON, it would be better to directly generate colModel and data in JSON format.